# informal semantics regarding CH and AC

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, terminology, math-history

why is the assertion $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ referred to as a *hypothesis*, whereas $$\forall \alpha( S_\alpha \ne \varnothing) \Rightarrow  \prod_\alpha S_\alpha \ne \varnothing$$ is called an *axiom*? is this merely a historical 'accident' or does it indicate a difference in the way these statements are interpreted?

Comment: It took me a while what was weird with the $(\forall\alpha S_\alpha\neq\varnothing)$. The quantifier ought to be outside! :-)

Comment: thx @AsafKaragila, i will endeavour to be more careful. btw is it (informally) still acceptable (as in some of the more ancient tracts on formal logic/"metamathematics") to use the period as a separator, i.e. $\forall \alpha.S_\alpha \ne \varnothing$? that was what i intended, tho' i was never wholly at ease with that usage. maybe you could suggest an example or two from MSE or MO which exemplify good practice in the punctuation of inline logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axiom of choice was something people had used without always noting that there is an assumption to be made in order to justify making infinitely many choices at once.

On the other hand, Cantor felt that there shouldn't be intermediate cardinals between the naturals and the reals, so he hypothesized that this is the case and spent a considerable amount of energy trying to prove that hypothesis.

You could also ask why Zorn's Lemma is not "Zorn's Axiom", but again, this is just a matter of naming something according to how it was born. If it was born as an assumption, it is an axiom or a postulate. If it was born as a theorem (namely a statement that was proved)  it will be a lemma or theorem or whatever. If it was born as a question which was open for quite some time, it will be an hypothesis or a conjecture.

Comment: thanks Asaf. i think your analysis is sound, though i seem to remember reading that both Kurt Gödel and Paul Cohen thought the last word may not have been said about CH. however my knowledge of these matters is still rather sparse.

Comment: @DavidHolden: Not sure about Cohen, but Gödel was a Platonist who really thought that CH was false. At one point he thought that the theory of large cardinals would produce the evidence to show this. (We now know that this was not to be.) There was also a "Gödel programme" to search for new axioms for set theory ("axiom" here in the classical meaning of an obviously true statement about the concept at hand) which would resolve CH. In some sense this search continues with the work of Hugh Woodin, Sy Friedman, and others.

Comment: @ArthurFischer from Cohen's "Set Theory and The Continuum Hypothesis" (2008 Dover reprint of 1966 publication by W.A.Benjamin Inc.p 151): "A point of view which the author feels may eventually come to be accepted is that CH is <i>obviously</i> false" (emphasis in original). his line of thought is that $\aleph_1$ is merely the 'simplest' way of generating (sic)  a higher ordinal, whereas $c$ (the cardinality of the continuum) is "in contrast, generated by a totally new and more powerful principle, namely, the Power Set Axiom..."

Comment: a further insight into Cohen's (informal) line of thinking here (from the same location) "The main reason one accepts the Axiom of Infinity is probably that we feel it absurd to think that the process of adding only one set at a time can exhaust the entire universe."